# I cant figure out how to do lookup properly (SAS)

Tags: sas

In Base SAS, I have a script with hash object to do table lookup. The condition as follow.
Table A is the original primary table which will take Table B to do lookup.
The lookup key is AssetName and Voltage. 
Voltage is always either 33 or 11.

So now we can imagine that it is Table A lookup with Table B by using AssetName and Voltage to get some data from Table B.

Lets have a look at the sample code that I have.

```
data ncpdm.ncp_load_re (drop=excp_code re_state re_supply_zone)
     work.excp_ncp_load_re;
  length excp_code $50 re_state re_supply_zone $30;

  if _n_=1 then do;
     declare hash pmu_list(dataset:"ncpdm.ncp_asset_pmu");
     pmu_list.definekey('assetname','voltage');
     pmu_list.definedata('region','zone','state_code','state',
                         'business_area_code','business_area',
                         'supply_zone_code','supply_zone',
                         'sub_supply_zone_code','sub_supply_zone',
                         'pmu_name','substation_name_tnbt','functional_location');
     pmu_list.definedone();
     call missing(region,zone,state_code,state,
                  business_area_code,business_area,
                  supply_zone_code,supply_zone,
                  sub_supply_zone_code,sub_supply_zone,
                  pmu_name,substation_name_tnbt,functional_location);
  end;
  set asset_re (RENAME=(pmu=assetname voltage=voltage_));
  data_dttm=datetime();

  voltage_=strip(voltage_);
voltage=cats('132/',voltage_);
mnemonic_tnbt=strip(mnemonic_tnbt);
 assetname=mnemonic_tnbt;


  rc=pmu_list.find();
  if (rc^=0) then do;
     excp_code='Exception: Mnemonic_tnbt and Voltage not mapped to PMU master list';
     output work.excp_ncp_load_re;
  end;
  else do;
  output ncpdm.ncp_load_re;
  end;

  keep mnemonic_tnbt excp_code re_state re_supply_zone
       region zone state_code state business_area_code business_area
       supply_zone_code supply_zone sub_supply_zone_code sub_supply_zone
       pmu_name substation_name_tnbt functional_location voltage
       re_state
re_station
re_ca_no
re_customer_name
re_capacity
re_commission_date
re_technology
pmu
ppu
ssu_pe
re_switch_no
voltage

period
 data_dttm
 active_flag                    
program             
scod_date               
kick_off_date       
iom_date
geo_longitude
geo_latitude;
run;
```

From my code above, i set those that cannot be mapped/lookup to output to excp table. I then use the same hash object code but with excp as data source to lookup the same table again, code as below.
(i  change Voltage to 33 or 11(the opposite of existing voltage).

```
/*2nd round lookup for failed record*/
data ncpdm.ncp_load_rev2 (drop=excp_code re_state re_supply_zone)
     work.excp_ncp_load_re (drop=excp_code re_state re_supply_zone);
  length excp_code $50 re_state re_supply_zone $30;

  if _n_=1 then do;
     declare hash pmu_list(dataset:"ncpdm.ncp_asset_pmu");
     pmu_list.definekey('assetname','voltage');
     pmu_list.definedata('region','zone','state_code','state',
                         'business_area_code','business_area',
                         'supply_zone_code','supply_zone',
                         'sub_supply_zone_code','sub_supply_zone',
                         'pmu_name','substation_name_tnbt','functional_location');
     pmu_list.definedone();
     call missing(region,zone,state_code,state,
                  business_area_code,business_area,
                  supply_zone_code,supply_zone,
                  sub_supply_zone_code,sub_supply_zone,
                  pmu_name,substation_name_tnbt,functional_location);
  end;
  set work.excp_ncp_load_re;
  data_dttm=datetime();

  if voltage='132/11' then voltage = '132/33';
  else if voltage='132/33' then voltage='132/11';

mnemonic_tnbt=strip(mnemonic_tnbt);
  assetname=mnemonic_tnbt;
re_state=state;
re_station=station;
re_ca_no=ca_no;
re_customer_name=applicant_name;
re_capacity=capacity;
re_commission_date=commission_date;
re_technology=technology;

geo_latitude=lat;
geo_longitude=lng;

  rc=pmu_list.find();
  if (rc^=0) then do;
     excp_code='Exception: Mnemonic_tnbt and Voltage not mapped to PMU master list';
     output work.excp_ncp_load_re;
  end;
  else do;
  output ncpdm.ncp_load_rev2;
  end;

  keep mnemonic_tnbt excp_code re_state re_supply_zone
       region zone state_code state business_area_code business_area
       supply_zone_code supply_zone sub_supply_zone_code sub_supply_zone
       pmu_name substation_name_tnbt functional_location voltage
       re_state
re_station
re_ca_no
re_customer_name
re_capacity
re_commission_date
re_technology
pmu
ppu
ssu_pe
re_switch_no
voltage

period
 data_dttm
 active_flag                    
program             
scod_date               
kick_off_date       
iom_date
geo_longitude
geo_latitude;
run;
```

Problem is, for those that doesn't have matching Voltage in my first hash object, I managed to lookup in the second hash object code BUT I still get un-mapped records. Once I append table generated from 1st hash object and 2nd hash object, i still get lesser records than my desired result.

I couldnt figure out on how to apply a better logic. Somehow i feel that my method of using 2nd hash object to lookup is not necessary but i just dont know what is the better way.

Is there a better way to that?

Comment: I really cannot follow what your issue is.  Can you provide a few sample data records and show what you want and how your current results are different than that?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a hash merge?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform both lookups in a single step.  After the first `find()` fails change the `key2` value to it's alternate value and perform another `find()`.  Note: For the case of no matches detected, the lookup satellite variables should be explicitly set to missing so that the output data set is accurate -- if not reset the satellite lookup variables will contain values from the most recent prior match.

Sample code:

This sample generates data for a main table and a lookup table.  Each table has some satellite variables that are to be carried into the output data sets.  A status variable is also created to indicate the kind of match or mismatch that occurred.

```
data have(keep=key1 key2 have:);
  length key1 $6 key2 $2;
  do _n_ = 1 to 5000;
    key1 = repeat(byte(26*ranuni(123)+rank('A')),5);
    key2 = ifc(ranuni(123) < 0.35, '11', '33');
    if ranuni(123) < 0.02 then key2 = '22';
    array have(3); * satellite (non-key) variables in have;
    do i = 1 to 3;
      have(i) = _n_ * 10000 + i;
    end;
    output;
  end;
  format have: 8.;
run;

data lookup(keep=key1 key2 look:);
  length key1 $6 key2 $2;
  array look(5); * satellite (non-key) variables in lookup;
  do i = 1 to 26;
    key1 = repeat(byte(i-1+rank('A')),5);
    array key2s(2) $2 _temporary_ ('11','33');
    do j = 1 to 2;      
      key2 = key2s(j);
      do k = 1 to 5;
        look(k) = i * 1000 + j * 100 + k;
      end;
      if ranuni(123) < 0.40 then output;
    end;
  end;
  format look: 8.;
run;

data match no_match;

  length key1 $6 key2 $2 match_status $30;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;

    if 0 then set lookup; * prep pdv at compilation time, set is never executed at runtime;

    declare hash lookup(dataset:'lookup');
    lookup.defineKey('key1', 'key2');
    do i = 1 to 5; drop i;
      lookup.defineData(cats('look',i));
    end;
    lookup.defineDone();
  end;

  set have;

  rc = lookup.find();

  if rc = 0 then do;
    match_status = 'match on actual keys';
    output match;
    return; * to top of step;
  end;

  * first lookup failed, try the alternate key2;

  if key2 = '11' then 
    key2='33';
  else
  if key2 = '33' then
    key2 = '11';
  else do;
    call missing (of look:); * clear lookup values that find() loaded at last prior match;
    match_status = 'no match, key2 invalid';
    output no_match;
    return; * to top of step;
  end;

  rc = lookup.find();

  if rc = 0 then do;
    match_status = 'match after key2 swap';
    output match;
    return; * to top of step;
  end;
  else do;
    call missing (of look:); * clear lookup values that find() loaded at last prior match;
    match_status = 'no match with 11 or 33';
    output no_match;
    return; * to top of step;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do understand your point. However, I am stuck on changing my script as per my post into the similar concept in your post. Is there a chance for you to help me further to edit my script ?

Comment: Each SO user has a profile that includes a "developer story".  They can edit that to include a website link. I think mine does and has a contact form.